# Video streaming - dealing with header 206 (php to HTML5)

Tags: php, http-headers, video-streaming, html5-video

As usual, it never works for me...

I try to stream video and I'm doing very well with the code below:

```
function send_back_video($video_path)
{
    ob_clean();
    $mime = "application/octet-stream"; // The MIME type of the file, this should be replaced with your own.
    $size = filesize($video_path); // The size of the file

    // Send the content type header
    header('Content-type: ' . $mime);

    // Check if it's a HTTP range request
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    {       
        // Parse the range header to get the byte offset
        $ranges = array_map(
            'intval', // Parse the parts into integer
            explode(
                '-', // The range separator
                substr($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 6) // Skip the `bytes=` part of the header
            )
        );

        // If the last range param is empty, it means the EOF (End of File)
        if(!$ranges[1]){
            $ranges[1] = $size - 1;
        }

        // Send the appropriate headers
        header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
        header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
        header('Content-Length: ' . ($ranges[1] - $ranges[0])); // The size of the range

        // Send the ranges we offered
        header(
            sprintf(
                'Content-Range: bytes %d-%d/%d', // The header format
                $ranges[0], // The start range
                $ranges[1], // The end range
                $size // Total size of the file
            )
        );

        // It's time to output the file
        $f = fopen($video_path, 'rb'); // Open the file in binary mode
        $chunkSize = 8192; // The size of each chunk to output

        // Seek to the requested start range
        fseek($f, $ranges[0]);

        // Start outputting the data
        while(true)
        {

            // Check if we have outputted all the data requested
            if(ftell($f) >= $ranges[1])
            {
                break;
            }

            // Output the data
            echo fread($f, $chunkSize);

            // Flush the buffer immediately
            @ob_flush();
            flush();
        }
    }
    else {
        // It's not a range request, output the file anyway
        header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

        // Read the file
        @readfile($file);

        // and flush the buffer
        @ob_flush();
        flush();
    }
}
```

"So if it works, what do you want?" - you might ask..

As I stated before, the code does a very good job, BUT there is 1 issue.

If I start to play video, php sends `header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content')` and this (video) request stays open till EOF, what means, I am FORCED to download entire video even if don't want to (let's say I'm clicking on the next video).

My JS removes video tag (this should ABORT request) and creates new video tag with new link. ABORT part is not happening.

Here you can see GET the example:
[image]

1. 1st - initial video get
2. 2nd - play button pressed
3. 3rd - navigate away - new DOM item created and waiting to appear.

So what I'm looking for, is some option to close the connection on navigate away.
I saw youtube does many GETs. As I understand every GET brings new "chunk" when previous "chunk" close to end. It's very good option, but it cancels buffering and I want to be able to buffer video.

P.S.

For sure I'm doing something wrong, I just can't see what.

P.P.S.

I'm not the author of the code.